# Issue signing XLSM files using OfficeSips and Signtool

Tags: excel, windows, ms-office, digital-signature

After installing vcredist, Windows SDK (specifically signing, everything else was skipped), and OfficeSips, I still cannot use Signtool to sign XLSM files.

I have made a folder in Program Files for all of the OfficeSips files, and I've registered msosip.dll and msosipx.dll. I've also made the key HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VBA, and populated it with REG_SZ Vbe71DllPath as the readme instructed. Despite all this, Signtool still comes back with "This file format cannot be signed because it is not recognized." when attempting to sign a macro-enabled Excel sheet. I have also attempted using wintrust.dll.ini as the readme instructed, but that doesn't work either, instead causing Signtool to terminate immediately instead of giving an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are probably running the 64bit version of signtool, msosip.dll and msosipx.dll are 32bit so can only be used by the 32bit version of signtool.exe.

In a powershell console you can run `gcp signtool` and it will tell you the path that signtool is being run from.

Generally speaking, if the path starts with `C:\Program Files(x86)` it is the 32bit version and if it starts with `C:\Program Files` it will be the 64bit version.

Comment: That was it!

yanno, looking back, this should've been obvious. It's in progfiles x86, but it's in the x64 subfolder in the windows sdk, i changed my path to x86 and it worked fine.